# how to find the sum of $1 - \ln(2) + \frac{(\ln(2))^2}{2!} - \frac{(\ln(2))^3}{3!} + \ldots $

Tags: sequences-and-series

find the sum of $1 - \ln(2) + \frac{(\ln(2))^2}{2!} - \frac{(\ln(2))^3}{3!} + \ldots $

I know the answer is 1/2 but i don't know why .

Comment: Have you ever seen the Taylor series for $e^x$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hint:

$$e^{-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^k}{k!}$$